# Matlab - open netcdf files from only specific subfolders

Tags: matlab, subdirectory, netcdf

I have several subfolders in my  `parentFolder` but I only want to read the .nc files from a few specific subfolders. I thought I had it figured out with this:

```
parentFolder = '/Users/AM/workspace/';
cd(parentFolder)

s1 = 'daytime/instant';
s2 = 'daytime/monthly';
s3 = 'nighttime/instant';
s4 = 'nightttime/monthly';

sub_f = {s1,s2,s3,s4};
s = strcat(parentFolder, sub_f);
    % 1x4 cell with pathnames to files

filePattern = fullfile(s, '*.nc'); 

ncFiles1 = cell(length(filePattern),1);

for k = 1:4
    ncFiles1{k} = dir(filePattern{k}); 
end

ncFiles = [ncFiles1{1}; ncFiles1{2}; ncFiles1{3}; ncFiles1{4}];

filename = cell(length(ncFiles),1);


for k = 1:length(ncFiles)

    filename{k} = ncFiles(k).name;

end
```

I ended up with a 131x1 cell array of all the filenames I wanted, but when I tried to read the data I got this error message:

```
Error using internal.matlab.imagesci.nc/openToRead (line 1259)

Could not open instant_SR_CR_DR_2008-07-01T00-15-56ZD_day_CFMIP2_2.90.nc for reading.
```

I know the files are okay because I can read them in by going to each subfolder individually. Is there a better way to read files out of specific subfolders? Any reason I'm getting that error when I try to open the files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide location of your matlab file(.m), Location of `daytime` directory and `current folder` location of matlab after running the code.

Comment: You haven't showed *how* you're attempting to read in the data and the inputs your attempting to use. That's the relevant information here...

Comment: And given that you `know the files are okay because I can read them in by going to each subfolder individually`, the logical first step is to make sure you're passing the *path* to whatever you're using to load the data because MATLAB can't magically figure that out for you if it's not in the current working directory.